# How to place numbers into certain groups?

Tags: c++, arrays

Okay so I will calculate distances. There will be a 20 distances groups that will get points when a match is found. How do I avoid writing conditions for each group?

Is there a shortcut to ---

```
if (distance>0)and(distance<=10)
{
    distance_group[1]=++1;
}
else
    if (distance>10)and(distance<=20)
    {
        distance_group[2]=++1;
    }
```

etc..... for all groups all the way to a number like 400

Each group gets points when a close match is found, but I don't want to write out all the groups conditions for getting a point, I might need 5000 groups instead of 20.

Any ideas?

Comment: what should happen if `distance==10`?

Comment: opps I forgot to add an <= sign sorry. But I'm still lost.

Answer (score 6):

You can calculate the group number like this:

```
int group_number = (distance-1)/10+1;
```

and then increment the count in that group:

```
++distance_group[group_number];
```

If distance==1, you have `(1-1)/10+1 == 1`.

If distance==2, you have `(2-1)/10+1 == 1`.

.
.
.

if distance==9, you have `(9-1)/10+1 == 1`.

if distance==10, you have `(10-1)/10+1 == 1`.

if distance==11, you have `(11-1)/10+1 == 2`.

etc.

Comment: Yes but how would I know what group it would be placed into. The groups would be issued by dividing two numbers. For example 640/10. Meaning you would have 64 groups. So a number like 64.999 would not have it's own group.

Comment: @AmadeusBojiuc: I'm not sure what you mean.  The group number is calculated as shown.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your example If distance==1, (1-1)/10+1  would not equal 1

Comment: Sorry if I'm confusing you guys. Here's one more examples. If I have a number like 64.567 and there's a group 64. How would I place it in there? Without having to check all 64 groups.

Comment: @AmadeusBojiuc: I broke it up into two statements.  Does that make it clearer?

Comment: @AmadeusBojiuc: Based on your original code, 64.567 seems like it would go into group 7, since it would be >60 and <=70.

Comment: Correct, so how would I go about matching it with that group without checking all 7 groups?

Comment: @AmadeusBojiuc: Just as shown.  If distance is 64.567, then group_number would come out as 7, since (64.567-1)/10+1 rounded down to an integer is 7.

Comment: If distance is a double, you need some casting here.